# [Javascript]Regex Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Tue,Sep,21,15:48:1,CEST,2010

I would replace the "," with a space.

I have tried:

```
string=string.replace("/,/g"," ");
```

and the result is:

```
Tue,Sep,21,15:48:1,CEST,2010
```

I have tried:

```
string=string.replace(","," ");
```

and the result is:

```
Tue Sep,21,15:48:1,CEST,2010
```

How can I replace all the "," with " "?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes around your regular expression and it will work:

```
string=string.replace(/,/g," ");
```

Answer (score 2):

"/,/g" is a string, not a regular expression

/,/g is a regular expression.

```
string=string.replace(/,/g," ");
```